# How to route specific addresses through a tunnel?

Tags: networking, routing, ip, tunneling

There are certain websites/services which I can only access from the subnet on which my server is located (think of the typical intranet scenario). Is there a way to transparently route traffic that go to these addresses through an SSH tunnel?

Consider the following setup:

My laptop is connected on the home network. It cannot access services on ips X and Y directly. I have an SSH tunnel to a server which is on a subnet that can actually access these services.

Can I somehow automatically encapsulate all the traffic to the subnets of X and Y to go through this tunnel, without having to run the entire VPN solution that would send all my traffic through the server? In other words: all traffic that goes to any other subnet should still go directly from the laptop, without passing through the server (using the tunnel).

Answer (score 7):

You can specify the interface through which to route traffic in the routing table:

```
sudo route add <host.com> -interface <ppp0>
```

Where host.com is the hostname or ip that you want to access through the interface, and ppp0 is the link identifier for your vpn shown with the `ifconfig` command.

Comment: Note: at least on ubuntu `-interface` isn't an option of `route` so the above suggestion gives a usage error.  Also how will this result in routing via the ssh tunnel as the OP asks?

Answer (score 5):

Recent versions of OpenSSH support tun/tap network devices for true VPN support. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH_VPN for some basic documentation (obviously intended for Ubuntu, but the basic principle applies elsewhere.)

Comment: Note that this requires root privileges on both the laptop and the gateway host.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I have not actually tested what I'm going to describe, and
indeed it can be completely wrong, but your question is so intriguing
that I cannot resist the temptation to draft an answer. :-)  Also, the
setup here depends on some `iptables` functionality that might exist
only on Linux.

Assuming you want to connect from your laptop to a specific port P1 on
server X1, to port P2 on server X2, etc. -- I am going to describe how
to route TCP traffic to these specific server+port pairs through an
SSH tunnel.  *Note:* the IP addresses X1,X2,etc are the IP addresses
of server as seen from the gateway host (the one you SSH into).

1. Select some unused local ports L1 (e.g. 10000), L2 (e.g. 10001), etc.  Ports L1, L2, ..., must be all distinct and their number should be equal to the number of distinct (Xn,Pn) server+port pairs.
2. Use `iptables` to redirect packets directed to Xn:Pn onto localhost:Ln

   iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d X1 --dport P1 -j DNAT --to-destination localhost:L1
   iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d X2 --dport P2 -j DNAT --to-destination localhost:L2
3. Now SSH to the gateway, using the `-L` option to tunnel traffic from localhost:Ln to (Xn, Pn):

   ssh gateway.server -L localhost:L1:X1:P1 -L localhost:L2:X2:P2 ...

Example:

```
# access webserver.intranet (port 80) through localhost:10080
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d webserver.intranet --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination localhost:10080
ssh gateway.server -L locahost:10080:webserver.intranet:80
```

Caveats:

- it only works for TCP, if it works at all...
- if you want to access more than one server, it's probably less work
  to setup a VPN
- it might still be easier to use SSH `-D` option to simulate a SOCKS
  proxy and tunnel all your traffic through that.

Comment: It actually works! (Sadly, it doesn't fit my specific situation, where I want to route traffic that originates from a virtual machine, not from localhost.)

Answer (score 1):

> subnets of X and Y to go through this
>   tunnel, without having to run the
>   entire VPN solution that would send
>   all my traffic through the server?

What you want is the definition of a VPN.

A VPN should not

> send
>   all [your] traffic through the server?

If it is, it is not setup properly.

It is assumed that any machine your trying to get access to via a Tunnel or VPN, by definition, not accessible via the Internet.  So, only the needed, non-Internet routable address should be routed down the VPN.

If you have a more complicated situation, like only machine X and Y and nothing else.  Your IT staff can put those on a subnet for you.  Then on your client computer, only route that subnet down the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I somehow automatically encapsulate all the traffic to the subnets of X and Y to go through this tunnel, without having to run the entire VPN solution that would send all my traffic through the server?

This is a bit strange at first glance because that's what a VPN will do for you.  SSH tends to be a point-to-point affair, the idea being that you connect one port on your local machine to the port of a remote machine elsewhere; it really wasn't designed for the type of traffic you envision.

> In other words: all traffic that goes to any other subnet should still go directly from the laptop, without passing through the server (using the tunnel).

Again, a VPN would take care of that.

If you are concerned about a "heavyweight" solution to getting secure VPN traffic (i.e. you don't want to monkey with it because it would be too complicated) you should really look at [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/), which will do exactly what you are describing.  No only would it encapsulate all of the traffic, but it can be done in a way that only traffic destined for those subnets will make the trip over the VPN pipe.  I will warn you that you will still need to edit a text file on the local and remote machine(s), but it's fairly easy to get running.

For your purposes, because you do not want the party in the middle (a server) to see your traffic, you would set up the VPN to connect directly from your machine to the remote machine.  Any routed packets would be encrypted before leaving your laptop, so you would have 100% end-to-end coverage.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, if you must "encapsulate all the traffic to the subnets," then you probably want to use VPN.

However, to access just a few services, you might want to use SSH's local port forwarding feature, which is really simple. For example, if you enter (from your laptop):

```
ssh -N -L 3333:localhost:2222 jump_box
```

then connecting to `localhost:3333` on your laptop will be just like connecting to `localhost:2222` from `jump_box`. You can use multiple -L options at once, and you can connect to services on other hosts if the ssd_config on `jump_box` allows it.

You can use `autossh` with `systemd` or the like to keep the tunnels up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you, wrap your ssh command into a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function control_c {
    echo -en "\n## Caught SIGINT; Clean up /etc/hosts and Exit \n"
    sed -i '' "/internal-wiki/d" /etc/hosts
    exit $?
}

trap control_c SIGINT
trap control_c SIGTERM

(sleep 5; open http://internal-wiki.example:8001 &)&
echo '127.0.0.1 internal-wiki.example' >> /etc/hosts
ssh -L8001:internal-wiki.example:8000 -f external-proxy.example -N
```

Explaining:

1. function that executes the cleanup on Control-C when issued
2. trap Control-C and shutdown
3. sleep, tell osx to open your site, get out of the way (the
   ampersand)
4. adds the entry to `/etc/hosts`
5. create the tunnel
6. when you ctrl-c, the functions kicks in and cleans up `/etc/hosts`
   with the transient entry